# Best way to ignore the success status of a call?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, try-catch

I have a situation where I want to ignore the success status of a call, and I am currently doing it like this:

```
try addr.functionCall() {} catch {}
```

I know I could do a low-level call like this:

```
(bool success,) = addr.call(data)
```

But I don't like this approach either because I have to explicitly do something to ignore the warning I get for not using the `success` variable.

Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

Comment: Comes down to personal opinion I think, but I prefer the former. It's very clear that you're intending to swallow the error, whereas the latter example is a little less clear. You could omit the left part of the 2nd example so you don't get an unused variable warning, but it just gives you a different warning.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, Nate. I agree that the former is clearer - I might just stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

With [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry), there is a neat way to ignore Solidity compiler warnings, and that is to use the [`ignored_error_codes`](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/tree/master/config) config option:

```
# ignore solc warnings for missing license and exceeded contract size
# known error codes are: ["unreachable", "unused-return", "unused-param", "unused-var", "code-size", "shadowing", "func-mutability", "license", "pragma-solidity", "virtual-interfaces", "same-varname"]
# additional warnings can be added using their numeric error code: ["license", 1337]
ignored_error_codes = ["license", "code-size"]
```